# Excel VBA - application.index function

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone help me when and why I have to use the `application.index` in the VBA?

```
Function elso(bemenet)

Dim kimenet(), koztes() As Variant
Dim i, j, n, m, k As Long
Dim sarok As Double

elso = 1
n = bemenet.Rows.count
m = bemenet.Columns.count
ReDim kimenet(n + 1, m + 1)

For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To m
        kimenet(i, j) = bemenet(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To n
    kimenet(i, m + 1) = Application.max(Application.Index(bemenet, i, 0))
Next i

For j = 1 To m
    kimenet(n + 1, j) = Application.Average(Application.Index(bemenet, 0, j))
Next j

For k = 1 To Application.max(n, m)
    sarok = sarok + (bemenet(k, k))
Next k

kimenet(n + 1, m + 1) = sarok
elso = kimenet

End Function
```

Comment: Function elso(bemenet)
Dim kimenet(), koztes() As Variant
Dim i, j, n, m, k As Long
Dim sarok As Double
elso = 1
n = bemenet.Rows.Count
m = bemenet.Columns.Count
ReDim kimenet(n + 1, m + 1)
For i = 1 To n
For j = 1 To m
kimenet(i, j) = bemenet(i, j)
Next j
Next i
For i = 1 To n
kimenet(i, m + 1) = Application.Max(Application.Index(bemenet, i, 0))
Next i
For j = 1 To m
kimenet(n + 1, j) = Application.Average(Application.Index(bemenet, 0, j))
Next j

Comment: For k = 1 To Application.Max(n, m)
sarok = sarok + (bemenet(k, k))
Next k
kimenet(n + 1, m + 1) = sarok
elso = kimenet
End Function

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in here and I don't know how to show my VBA code in a 'normal' view.

Comment: Put the code in your question. Highlight it and then hit `Ctrl + K`

Comment: @EvelinDanás have a read [of this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be for getting specific values stored in memory from worksheets.  Please see https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/

Answer (score 2):

It's a worksheet function for pulling values from a range. The following function identically:

```
Application.Index(Array, Row_Number, Column_Number)

Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Array, Row_Number, Column_Number)
```